# angularfire $waitForSignIn() usage?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I'm trying to figure out what is the ussage of `$waitForSignIn()`

the docs says:

> $waitForSignIn() which returns a promise fulfilled with the current
>   authentication state. This is useful when you want to grab the
>   authentication state before the route is rendered

But how would this work?

They say you should implement is as following (from: [link](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers)):

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
      controller: "HomeCtrl",
      templateUrl: "views/home.html",
      resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          // $waitForSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
          return Auth.$waitForSignIn();
        }]
      }
    })
    .state("account", {
      // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
      controller: "AccountCtrl",
      templateUrl: "views/account.html",
      resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          // $requireSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
          // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
          return Auth.$requireSignIn();
        }]
      }
    });
}]);
```

so you would expect that the HomeCtrl get's loaded when the users is signed in? but this is loaded with the currentAuth on `null` when no user is logged in,

I then tried putting a watcher on the `currentAuth` no change when the user is logged in. But no events were triggered for logging in nor out

Then next I was thinking that it only waits when you are trying to login (via a popup for example). So I launched the popup and then directly switched to the home page, but then I get a `null` from the `currentAuth` and if I refresh I get my userdata.

So what's the point? just so you can resolve a user when one is available?

Comment: We would need to see your controller code, you need to be injecting currentAuth into your controller before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect your HomeCtrl to know if a user is signed in or not and your accout route to restric acces if a user is not signedin.